# how to generate string of letters based on some parameters

Tags: r, string, replace, words

I have a set of sentences with a different number of words in each sentence. I need to replace each word with a string of letters, but the string of letters needs to be based on specific criteria. For example, the letter 't' can be replaced only by the letters 'i', 'l', 'f'; the letter 'e' can be replaced only by 'o' or 'c', and so on, for each letter of the alphabet. Also, spaces between words need to be kept intact, as well as full stops, apostrophes and other symbols of punctuation. Following an example:
ORIGINAL SENTENCE: He loves dog.
SENTENCE WITH STRING OF LETTERS: Fc tcwoz bcy.

Is there a way to automatise this procedure in R? Thank you.

ADDED: I need to do this replacement for about 400 sentences. The sentences are stored in a variable of a data frame (data$sentences).

Comment: So, you need to use a random char from a defined set per each char? What have you tried so far? Please share.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `strsplit`. you can use split="" argument to get each character as a separate element. Then you'd build some mapping. Finally put it together with `paste(..., collapse="")`. Without more details as to the mapping, it is not possible to help further.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**: some code refactoring, added a simple fallback strategy to deal with missing characters (so we can encode ALL the characters in a given string, even if we don't have an exact one-to-one mapping), and added the example loop over a vector of strings.

```
# we define two different strings to be encode
mystrings <- c('bye', 'BYE')

# the dictionary with the replacements for each letter
# for the lowercase letters we are defining the exact entries
replacements <- {}
replacements['a'] <- 'xy'
replacements['b'] <- 'zp'
replacements['c'] <- '91'
# ... 
replacements['e'] <- 'xyv'
replacements['y'] <- 'opj'

# then we define a generic "fallback" entry
# to be used when we have no clues on how to encode a 'new' character
replacements['fallback'] <- '2345678'


# string, named vector -> character
# returns a single character chosen at random from the dictionary
get_random_entry <- function(entry, dictionary) {

  value <- dictionary[entry]

  # if we don't know how to encode it, use the fallback
  if (is.na(value)) {
    value <- dictionary['fallback']
  }

  # possible replacement for the current character
  possible.replacements <- strsplit(value[[1]], '')[[1]]

  # the actual replacement
  result <- sample(possible.replacements, 1)

  return(result)
}

# string, named vector -> string
# encode the given string, using the given named vector as dictionary
encode <- function(s, dictionary) {

  # get the actual subsitutions 
  substitutions <- sapply (strsplit(s,'')[[1]], function(ch) {

    # for each char in the string 's'
    # we collect the respective encoded version
    return(get_random_entry(ch, dictionary))

  }, USE.NAMES = F,simplify = T);

  # paste the resulting vector into a single string
  result <- paste(substitutions, collapse = '')

  # and return it
  return(result);
}

# we can use sapply to process all the strings defined in mystrings
# for 'bye' we know how to translate
# for 'BYE' we don't know; we'll use the fallback entry
encoded_strings <- sapply(mystrings, function(s) {
                                        # encode a single string
                                        encode(s, replacements)
                                     }, USE.NAMES =  F)

encoded_strings
```

Comment: It works perfectly with the string you have provided, thanks! If I need to use it for many sentences though, I may need a for loop at the beginning? In order to run this procedure for each row (i.e. each sentence)  of my variable in the data frame.

Comment: yes, substantially you could just wrap the part from "# get the actual subsitutions " to the end of the script into a single function and call it for all your individual strings to be encoded. please let me know if you need an example, in that case I'll update my answer. thanks

Comment: Leonardo Foderaro, if you could provide an example I would be very grateful. I thought I should use `for(i in 1:nrow(data)) { }` but before setting the string to be encoded, and then to define `s` as data$sentences (but I am not sure how to do this), as each row of data$sentences will be the string to be encoded.

Comment: I'm about to go for a job meeting and I can't code too much. I've edited my answer to add wrap the code into a function and call it in a loop. Probably it's not the most efficient solution but it should work. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Leonardo, thanks for your changes. It works fine now except that it does not keep the spaces between words, it does not replace capital letters with capital letters, and it ignores the punctuation.

Comment: glad to be useful! for the lowercase, check the function "tolower", to transform your input before it gets encoded. For the punctuation, you can define additional entries in the 'replacements' dictionary, or you could modify the function to use a sort of 'catch-all' for all the unspecified mappings. now I'm a bit busy, if you need an example I can modify my answer a bit later. please remember to check it as accepted ;-)

Comment: Last question, how can I print and save only the replacement sentences? (without original sentence --> replacement sentence). Thank you very very much!